# How can i set scroll bar to Multiple Select and Dynamic Autocomplete serarch box jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to set a scroll bar to the Multiple Select and Dynamic Autocomplete search box here I set scroll bar but it's not displaying my image is

[image: My image]

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is there, the problem is that the drop-down part is so large (and clipped off) that the scrollbar is not needed. You need to limit the max-height of the drop-down.

Comment: Hi, How can i set this height i am unable to set since last one hour i am searching for that here i am using `jquery.magicsearch.js` script here taking height dynamically based on options

Comment: I see there is a dropdownMaxItem field in the options of that plugin, maybe you could use that. Worth investigating that at the example site the dropdown somehow gets a max-height inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an alternitive its like a filter search you dont need drop down:

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kyrcha/ULSy3/6/)

```js
// Angular

var phonecatApp = angular.module('app', []);

phonecatApp.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        'name': 'Item 1'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 2'
    }, {
        'name': 'Account 3'
    }, {
        'name': 'Account 4'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 5'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 6'
    }, {
        'name': 'User 7'
    }, {
        'name': 'User 8'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 9'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 10'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 11'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 12'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 13'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 14'
    }, {
        'name': 'User 15'
    }, {
        'name': 'User 16'
    }, {
        'name': 'Person 17'
    }, {
        'name': 'Person 18'
    }, {
        'name': 'Person 19'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 20'
    }, ];
});

// jQuery
$('.dropdown-menu').find('input').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.dropdown.dropdown-scroll .dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.search-control {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown dropdown-scroll" ng-app="app">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Select<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        <li role="presentation">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm search-control"> <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Query" ng-model="query"></input>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat='item in items | filter:query'> <a href="#"> {{item.name}} </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

also i noticed you said you where useing magicsearch so i found these options to customize it maybe youll be able to use them to set the hieght: I eecoment you ser the max results in that setting if all else fails to cutt down the size of results!

```
 $('#basic').magicsearch({

   // array or string or function or url (for AJAX)
   dataSource: [],       

   // 'ajax'  
  type: '',

  // ajax options
   ajaxOptions: {},

   // unique id
  id: '',  

  // generate input[type="hidden"]?
  hidden: false, 

  // string or array to search through
  fields: '',  

   // data format           
  format: '',   

   // input format
  inputFormat: '',

  // max number of results
  maxShow: 5, 

  // clear the input when no option is selected
  isClear: true,

  // show selected options
  showSelected: true,

  // show dropdown button
  dropdownBtn: false,

  // max number of results in the dropdown
  dropdownMaxItem: 8,

   // multiple select
  multiple: false, 

  // true = no limit
   maxItem: true,

   // show multiple skins
  showMultiSkin: true,

   // multiple styles
    multiStyle: {},

  // multiple fields
  multiField: '', 

  // show on focus
  focusShow: false,

  // text when no results
  noResult: '',

  // custom skin
  skin: '', 

  // callbacks
  disableRule: function(data) {
  return false;
  },
  success: function($input, data) {
      return true;
  },
  afterDelete: function($input, data) {
  return true;
  }

});
```

Comment: Hi, @User98764431, I put this  maxShow: 5, but it display only 5 out of 20 items it's not working